# Capture Groups in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, regex, c++-cli

Hi i am trying to capture a substring from a bigger string using regex in C++/CLI
Here is the Code:

```
System::String^ str_path = "C:\\users\\Downloads\\myfile.pl";
Regex^ pat_scriptname = gcnew Regex("(.[^\.]*)\.pl");
Match^ scrpt_name = pat_scriptname->Match(str_path);
System::String^ filename = scrpt_name->Value;
```

Here i just want to capture the substring "myfile" only ...but it is not working,
The output saved in `filename` is always "myfile.pl"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code change you can just use the following regex: `[^\\]+(?=\.pl$)`, in C++ it has to be written as `[^\\\\]+(?=\\.pl$)`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/aUeP-Jo2VVDeFK1K)

Another question, why do you use regex for it? Why not the following code?

```
System::String^ filename = System::IO::Path::GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple things:

First, you need more backslashes. `\.` in C++/CLI is escaping the period, not inserting a backslash into the string. (You did it right in the path, don't forget to do it in the regex.) Note that the compiler is giving you a warning here: `warning C4129: '.' : unrecognized character escape sequence`.

```
gcnew Regex("(.[^\\.]*)\\.pl");
                 ^^    ^^
```

Second, inside the `[]`, I assume you want to match all characters other than period and backslash. With it reading `"[^\\.]"`, it will match all characters other than a period. (The backslash is escaping the period in the Regex, making it an explicit period instead of any character.) Therefore, we need to escape both the backslash and the period.

```
gcnew Regex("(.[^\\\\\\.]*)\\.pl");
                 ^^  ^^ escape the period
                 ^^ escape the backslash
```

You said you wanted the output to be `myfile`. With that leading `.`, it's matching the backslash just before `myfile`, so let's get rid of that.

```
gcnew Regex("([^\\\\\\.]*)\\.pl");
```

Now, the call to `->Value`. That ends up getting us `Group[0]->Value`, which is the full regular expression that was matched. Quoting [Match.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx):

> If the regular expression engine can find a match, the first element of the GroupCollection object returned by the Groups property contains a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern. Each subsequent element represents a captured group, if the regular expression includes capturing groups.

Since we want the first captured group:

```
String^ filename = scrpt_name->Groups[1]->Value;
```

Final code:

```
String^ str_path = "C:\\users\\Downloads\\myfile.pl";
Regex^ pat_scriptname = gcnew Regex("([^\\\\\\.]*)\\.pl");
Match^ scrpt_name = pat_scriptname->Match(str_path);
String^ filename = scrpt_name->Groups[1]->Value;

Debug::WriteLine(filename);
```

Output:

```
myfile
```